# WPML Plugin Not displaying multilingual Menus

Tags: customization, plugin-development, menus, multi-language

I'm using WordPress 3.0 Menus, which the WPML (wordpress multilingual) plugin [claims to have added support for in a recent release](http://wpml.org/2010/07/wpml-1-8-0-with-multilingual-menus/).  I am using the most current version of the plugin.

My problem is that using the following to call my nav menus

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'menu_id' => 'menu-primary-navigation' ) ); ?>
```

is pulling up only the English translation of the menu.

Here is an image of the WPML admin panel and how the menus are setup multilingual:

[link to image] http://cl.ly/42RW
[link to image] http://cl.ly/42o0

You can see the site currently in development:

http://anasmadance.com.s66112.gridserver.com/

The problem is that when you go to the French translated page, the menu is still in English (despite the fact that I've already set up the French menu)

http://anasmadance.com.s66112.gridserver.com/fr/

Comment: Can you check if it works with the default theme.

Comment: Good point. It doesn't, it's a bug in the plugin, see below for workaround.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up having to manually detect the language, here's how I solved it:

```
<?php if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'fr')
        {  
        // display the menu en francais 
            wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'Navigation principale', 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'menu_id' => 'menu-primary-navigation' ) );       
        } 
        else {  
        // show them the menu in English
            wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'Primary Navigation', 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'menu_id' => 'menu-primary-navigation' ) );
        }; ?>
```